# Por quê o Python considera que uma string vazia ('' ou "") está presente em uma variável simples com caracteres, mas não em uma composta?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

Ao fazer programas básicos pedindo o input do usuário, e testando se está vazio com in em função de outra variável que define as entradas possíveis, me deparo com o seguinte:

```
if '' in 'abc':
    print('not ok')
else:
    print('ok')

>>> not ok
```

e:

```
if '' in ['abc'] or '' in ('abc',) or '' in {'abc'}:
    print('not ok')
else:
    print('ok')

>>> ok
```

Se ''/"" está presente em strings em variáveis simples, por que não está presente em strings em variáveis compostas, ou vice-versa? Qual a diferença? Existe alguma explicação para isso?

[Link de outra pergunta relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27603885/why-is-true-returned-when-checking-if-an-empty-string-is-in-another) (inglês), com respostas bem completas para quem tiver maiores dúvidas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este comportamento pode ser encontrado na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details):

> For container types such as list, tuple, set, frozenset, dict, or collections.deque, the expression x in y is equivalent to any(x is e or x == e for e in y).

Isto é, traduzindo, para coleções de dados a expressão `x in y` é equivalente a verificar a igualdade de x com cada elemento da coleção y. Se algum deles retornar verdadeiro, então `x in y` retorna `true`.

Já para strings, no mesmo link podemos verificar:

> For the string and bytes types, x in y is True if and only if x is a substring of y. An equivalent test is y.find(x) != -1. Empty strings are always considered to be a substring of any other string, so "" in "abc" will return True.

Traduzindo, `x in y` onde y é uma string temos o retorno verdadeiro se e somente se x for uma sub-string de y. A documentação também diz que uma string vazia sempre vai ser considerada como contida em outra string.

Uma [string vazia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadeia_vazia) é matematicamente considerada substring de qualquer outra string pois é o elemento neutro da concatenação.

Se você se perguntar:

> Existe como encaixar essa **String Vazia** em alguma outra string para formar a string "ABCDE"?

a resposta vai ser sim:

> "" + "ABCDE" = "ABCDE"

o que por definição leva à conclusão de que `"" in "ABCDE"` deve retornar verdadeiro.

[Link de resposta relacionada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43730259/10746978) (em inglês)